# Object.prototype pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I do not understant, how to use Object.prototype pattern with classes (es6);

This is my code, I'm not sure, that I've used Object.prototype in the right way

```
    class Course{ 
     constructor(title, author) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
      }
    }


    Course.prototype.toString = function (arguments) {
        console.log(this.title + "... Author: " + this.author);
    };

    var course_1 = new Course("Bootstrap 4", "Paul");
    var course_2 = new Course("Design Patterns", "Paul");

    course_1.toString();
    course_2.toString();

}
```

Should I use something different?

Comment: You should just put the function in the `class`.

Comment: You can make `toString` a method in the `class`, but yes that assignment is correct

Comment: That is correct, but the new `class` syntactic sugar allows you to simply define `.toString` as a method inside the block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing an application using es6 classes is an *alternative* to developing using the prototype pattern directly.

Under the hood, es6 classes actually compile down to the prototype structure. But es6 classes tend to be easier to read, and when your application gets very large this can make all the difference.

In your case you would place the methods you want attached to the prototype inside the class you've created. This looks more similar to classic object oriented programming, as you would see in C++ or Java.

You can read more about es6 classes on MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Per your example:

```
class Course { 
 constructor(title, author) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
  }

  toString(arguments) {
     console.log(this.title + "... Author: " + this.author);
  }
}

var course_1 = new Course("Bootstrap 4", "Paul");
var course_2 = new Course("Design Patterns", "Paul");

course_1.toString();
course_2.toString();
```

Comment: As a prototype-based language, there is no class system nor classes in ES6. Saying the "ES6 class system is an alternative" is misleading and incorrect.

Comment: Writing an application using es6 classes is an alternative to writing it using the prototype pattern. I made it clear that this is for the benefit of the developer more than anything else.

Comment: You are simply wrong. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes. They were introduced as ' primarily syntactical sugar over JavaScript's existing prototype-based inheritance'. That does not mean they do not 'exist'. You are grasping at straws here just to troll the post.

Comment: @AlexanderGriffin The `class` keyword is a syntactic sugar in which it automatically creates and extends the prototype chain. In fact, `Course` is a merely a function that acts as a constructor when used with the `new` keyword. For more details, check out the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). ECMAScript is strictly a prototype-based language and there is absolutely no classes whatsoever.

Comment: Yes, that's what I just said. Thank you.

Comment: @AlexanderGriffin Have you ever read the specification? There is no such thing as classes defined in the specification. Classes _do not exist_. We have objects with prototypes, but they do not come from classes.

Comment: I don't get why you are still trying to argue this. If you look order of comments, I stated that it was 'syntactical' sugar before you did. You're arguing the same point I've already made. The OP asked about how to use the class syntax, and an answer was provided that met the criteria of making a post. If you want to argue syntactical existence, I advise you take your argument elsewhere - we're done here.

Answer (score 4):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

ES6 classes is syntax sugar that allows you to avoid using Object.prototype, you simply define class methods like this:

```
    class Course{ 
         constructor(title, author) {
            this.title = title;
            this.author = author;
          }

         toString(arguments) {
            console.log(this.title + "... Author: " + this.author);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your following code:

```js
class Course {
  constructor(title, author) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
  }
}


Course.prototype.toString = function(arguments) {
  console.log(this.title + "... Author: " + this.author);
};

var course_1 = new Course("Bootstrap 4", "Paul");
var course_2 = new Course("Design Patterns", "Paul");

course_1.toString();
course_2.toString();
```

A class is nothing more than syntactic sugar which resembles the functionality of a constructor function. We can observe this more depth in the following example:

```js
class Person {
}

console.log(typeof Person);
```

The class Person is actually a constructor function object. Just like normal constructors functions we can extend the prototype by putting properties on the prototype object.

So in your example:

```
Course.prototype.toString = function(arguments) {
  console.log(this.title + "... Author: " + this.author);
};
```

What actually happens under the hood is that you are putting a property called toString on the `Course` constructor function object.